# Working with Database using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml

I am Working on a project (C#) in the university and they said that we can't use a DBMS like SQL Server so we decide to use Linq and XML...we learned some basics in Linq to Xml But really we don't know how we can create tables and fields and work with them in Xml.any suggestions ?

Comment: You have to get rid of the idea of tables and field if you use XML. SQL server is a _relational_ database, while XML is a _hierarchical_ one. But this is just a side note, not an answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest option would be a Typed Dataset saved to an XML file. (With or without LINQ)

You would use it just like an RDBMS, but it isn't an RDMS, so it should be allowed.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a single user application you can just create a serializable class and use that to store your data. Then when your app is closed the data class is serialized (binarily) to a file, and when the app starts it reads the file and all your data is still there.

[Here is a simple example from the docs.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: it is a Task Management Project , do you think serialization will help ?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use tables, you can create a Typed DataSet and Save/Load it as (proprietary) XML.

A DataSet can hold multiple tables + relations between them.

Comment: The XML produced by a typed dataset is not proprietary.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a bit rusty on this. There is 'normal' XML and the DiffGram stuff. Forgot which API provides what.

Comment: sorry but what is "not proprietary"?